# Does MySQL automatically re-format dates inserted in to a column of type DATETIME?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, datepicker

I understand the format of `DATETIME` in MySQL is `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`.

I am using Bootstrap datepicker which posts a value like `07/30/2014`. How can I get that changed to '2014-07-30 00:00:00`?

I don't want the user to see hours etc. but it must be in the string. Is datepicker able to output a string like this?

### SQL

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO bookings (forename, surname, site, badge, start, end) VALUES (:forename, :surname, :site, :badge, :start, :end)");
...
$stmt->bindParam(':start', $start);
$stmt->bindParam(':end', $end);
```

Comment: No it doesn't, you're expected to know the data formats that you're working with: tools like datepicker, languages like PHP and even MySQL functions can help convert dates from one format to another, but only you can tell them what format to convert from and to

Answer (score 1):

yes it is ,but if its a string you should you use `STR_TO_DATE()` to convert it  like this :

```
$msql ="insert into table (birthdate)value(STR_TO_DATE('$yourdate','%d/%m/%Y'))";
mysql_query($msql);
```

what i did : 
i converted the string `$yourdate` to a DateTime value.

**PS** : the `%d/%m/%Y` should be the format of the date in your string not the one on the server example :
if you had a date like this `22/2/2014` that should work fine, but if you had it like this : `2/22/2014` you should give it this :`'%m/%d/%Y'`

Comment: >>you should give it this :'%m/$d/%Y' Please fix the $$$

Comment: Hi. Thanks. Should I do this in the `INSERT` or `bindParam`?

Comment: actually if you are using bindparam there is no need for all that stuff ,just give it the  string normaly and excute your query

Comment: But `$start` and `$end` are like `07/30/2014`, doesn't it need to be converted?

Comment: i tell you what just give it the bindparam like that if it doesnt work try then to do this :
in the query :
inset into ...... STR_TO_DATE(:start,'%d/%m/%Y'),STR_TO_DATE(:end,'%d/%m/%Y'))
and give it the params normaly